# Split the dataset in train and test based on the group value?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the following dataset: (If I group by the data with '**group_name**', the data will look like:)

[image]

I want to split the dataset into train and test set based on the  `**group_name**` feature. For example, if I want 80:20 ratio, then the train and test set will look like (i.e. in the group-by function):

Train Set:

[image]

Test Set:

[image]

Thus, the  80:20 ratio is considered in the above example. Also, the above examples shown are the results of the groupby function applied to the actual dataset.

Comment: can you please post the original df so it can be copied and tested on

Answer (score 2):

Get the training with

`training = df.groupby('group_name').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.8))`

Then get the testing with the other index

`testing = df.loc[set(df.index) - set(training.index.get_level_values(1))]`

Answer (score 1):

Hey sklearn has many types of train test split, one of them is stratifysplit
simply:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, stratify = df['column_to_groupby'], random_state=0)
```

it will split each group based on test_size you defined.

Answer (score 0):

just try the sklearn lib. Based on your purpose, following methods could be try. They are  groupkflod, or GroupShuffleSplit.
[image]
[image]
Here is the example for groupkfold :

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
groups = np.array([0, 0, 2, 2])
group_kfold = GroupKFold(n_splits=2)
group_kfold.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)

print(group_kfold)

for train_index, test_index in group_kfold.split(X, y, groups):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    print(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
```

for more detail, Visualizing cross-validation behavior in scikit-learn article could provide detail info. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_cv_indices.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-cv-indices-py.